# Prove that if $z$ is good then so is $z + r$ for every $r \in R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, complex-numbers

> Let $$R = \left\{\frac{a + b\sqrt{-19}}{2}:a,b \in \mathbb{Z}, a \equiv b \mod 2 \right\} = \mathbb{Z} \left[\dfrac{1+\sqrt{-19}}{2} \right] = \mathbb{Z}[\alpha].$$ Note that $R$ is an integral domain.
>
> Call a complex number $z = x + iy$ *good* if there exists $a,b \in R$ such that $N(zb-a) < 1.$

(Note: $N(z) = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ denotes the complex norm function)

> (i) Prove that if the complex number $v = \dfrac{m}{n}$ is good then so is $v + r$ for every $r \in R$.

How do we prove this?

If we assume that $v$ is good. Then there exists $a,b \in R$ such that $N(vb-a) < 1.$ But I don't see how this would imply that $N((v+r)b-a)$ is also good. Any hints appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead consider $N((v+r)b-(a+rb))$.